# Using ConsRank in R Studio

Tags: r, statistics

Installed both R studio and ConsRank package but i have little R and Math knowledge.
I need to understand how to calculate and reach the result of the formula in attached files.
To solve this problem, correlation coefficient τx used which is intruduced by Emond and Mason (2002)
I tried to use ConsRank functions but my R knowledge was not enough.

`Formula`[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsDn2.png)
`Matrix`[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ6rL.png)
`Result`[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPogi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to install and load the package `ConsRank` using the following codes:

```
install.packages('ConsRank', dependencies=T)
library(ConsRank)
```

If you successfully load the package, you are good to go. The next step is to read the documentation of the package ([Click Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConsRank/ConsRank.pdf)) in which you will learn about what functions you will need and there are some different examples that help you understand the input and outputs.

Let me know if you needed any help running your scripts. Good Luck.